# Git push to selected branch

Tags: git

Is there shortcut that will allow to push to selected branch?

It can be a command, or something similar:

```
git push branch
```

that will run this code:

```
git push origin $(git branch | grep '*' | sed -e 's/* //')
```

Comment: shouldn't be this the default behavior of `git push` without any argument? If not, maybe I didn't understand what you want to do

Comment: I don't quite understand the question but git push origin HEAD:branch works very well...

Comment: @Martin: too much typing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "new" simple mode is what you need.

From git v1.7.11 release notes:

> A new mode for push, "simple", which is a cross between "current" and "upstream", has been introduced. "git push" without any refspec will push the current branch out to the same name at the remote repository only when it is set to track the branch with the same name over there. The plan is to make this mode the new default value when push.default is not configured.

Use new mode:

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

So you just do `git push` and it push current branch to a matching (tracked) remote branch.

Comment: Depending on what exactly the desire is either (or both) of `current` or `upstream` might also do what the OP wants here. As that snippet of docs says `simple` is a cross between the two (i.e. the behaviour from `upstream` with restrictions on name from `current`).